# SharePoint workflow suspended

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

My workflow is suspended in "Start a task process" line.
The error i getting in the sharepoint online is this:

> *RequestorId: 43b1dc3f-3e9e-cd90-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: ContentTypeId at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity Throw If Sequence Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.OperatingWebContextScope Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.SingleTask Sequence DynamicActivity Subroutine If Serial Tasks If SequenceMicrosoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.CompositeTask Document author signature process Sequence Flowchart TestWF(HJ5)(2013).WorkflowXaml_2237883c_5053_4c27_8fa1_e1955a82c20d *

This is my workflow:
[image: *enter image description here*]

Any idea what problem is this?

Feel free to ask for further information

Comment: Can you do some basic troubleshooting? Log a message after each command, so you at least know which command causes the problem.

Comment: I tried to log message between each command and i found that the workflow is suspended in command "Start a process with parameter...", which i have no idea what causes the problem...

Comment: I auther i cant understand your answer can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what is the problem.

The problem is I haven't change to the corresponding custom content type for the outcome when assigning the task...

Comment: thanks for posting your answer. You should accept it as the solution, so the question does not remain unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be happened, if the workflow could find the user. In our case, we get the user from another list based on custom field entry (Project Online). And the entry has space in front of it, so the workflow couldn't get the data and it failed with that error message.